# pigpiod pid listen on port 8888

Tags: node.js, pigpio

My nodejs app is using pigpio. It keeps getting error because port pigpiod is listen on port 8888 already. I can kill -9 the process but when I restart pi port 8888 is jammed up again. How do i solve this issue? Should i remove the npm pigpio libary and reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify port by running `pigpiod` daemon with parameter `-p <portnumber>`

Example: If you want to run `pigpiod` on port `1234`

`pigpiod -p 1234`

Comment: there should be config file in `/etc/...` but I have no Raspberry with me so I can't verify it.

Comment: Thanks; Ultimately I need to completely reinstall npm and pm2. Every thing works great now.